# Android Studio and disable preview layout

Tags: android, android-studio

I don't have fast computer so if I am creating layout, my computer is stuck firmly. Is it possible to disable the preview in real time? It's nice if I could generate a preview of the request.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can hide the preview by simply pressing `Shift + Escape` (on windows) or hit the icon at the top right of the "preview" header.

Comment: Ok but it's only hide the panel. It's running all time, I think.